# NEO4j:Optimization of search cypher queries

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

We are using neo4j cypher queries for searching in our website. So, long everythng is going fine except the optimization of queries. We are getting search results but not exactly what we are expecting may be lack of experience and full knowledge about cypher queries.

> In a textbox the search string is been send to the query on key up
>   handler means on entering each letter its going to execute query. Like
>   for eg. **v** then **a** like this and untill we enter space it will
>   treat it as one string and the result will be shown accordingly, but
>   the issue is as we enter space and start writing letters and then again will form a string the result fluctates badly.
>
> ***EXAMPLE:***
>
> QUERY 1 : `MATCH (n:user)<-[:userinteresttag]-(tag) where
>       ANY(m in split(n.username," ") where  m STARTS WITH 'vartika' )
>       RETURN distinct n.username` [image: QUERY 1 RESULT]

QUERY2: `MATCH (n:user)<-[:userinteresttag]-(tag) where
    ANY(m in split(n.username," ") where  m STARTS WITH 'vartika' or m STARTS WITH 'jain')
    RETURN distinct n.username order by n.username`

**ISSUE:-**
Since I am showing you the search through full string not by separated letters, still as it can be visible in the images that vartika jain which we expect to come as first result move to 2 which should not be the case.

As, when we work for key up handler then search result vartika jain goes to last position which is not we wanted.

[image: QUERY2 RESULT]

QUESTION:- SO, is there any way to optimize the result, so that we can get the best results as we get in google search.

Comment: You want to add some business rules defining how the results should be ordered. You should start by writing down what those rules are, not just say "the current order (which is actually defined in your QUERY2) does not satisfy us": maybe you want the results by decreasing number of submatches, or maybe it's something else. You could even try implementing them... Besides, splitting the username in the query is not going to be efficient as the number of users grows, it will need to scan all the users, load the property, split it, do comparisons, when you could benefit from an index.

Comment: May be I have to study more about cypher queries.

Comment: Regardless of Cypher, you should specify how you expect the results to be ordered. Then you can worry about implementing it.

Comment: I want vartika jain at the top and all the other result below

Comment: That's not a specification, that's an example. Why should it be the first result? Because you're searching on multiple terms and want the results with the most matching terms first? Once you've defined that, you can model your data or write your queries accordingly. But the onus is on you, SO isn't there to write your specification or application for you. Rephrase your question, include the relevant elements, what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should count the number of matches and order by that.

```
MATCH (n:user)
WITH n, size([m in split(n.username, ' ') WHERE m STARTS WITH 'vartika' OR m STARTS WITH 'jain']) AS matches
RETURN n.username
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

I removed the `[:userinteresttag]` relationship and `tag` node since you aren't using it in your query.

Example from the movie graph:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p, size([x IN split(p.name, ' ') WHERE x STARTS WITH 'Tom' OR x STARTS WITH 'Hanks']) AS matches
RETURN p.name, matches
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 5

╒════════════╤═══════╕
│p.name      │matches│
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│Tom Hanks   │2      │
├────────────┼───────┤
│Tom Cruise  │1      │
├────────────┼───────┤
│Tom Skerritt│1      │
├────────────┼───────┤
│Tom Tykwer  │1      │
├────────────┼───────┤
│Keanu Reeves│0      │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

But really you should store their first and last name in separate properties, index them, and use `STARTS WITH` on those indexed properties.

Comment: As this operation is not optimized by an index, I would add a pre-filter like: MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name CONTAINS 'Tom' which will use an index to find the initial set.